# unwanted behaviour with getParentFile() with uploading files via xp:fileUpload

Tags: java, jsf, xpages

We are noticing unwanted behaviour with uploading files via xp:fileUpload control. sometimes users get files from other users uploaded.

the files are named the same but the content differes.

I was using:

```
File correctedFile = new File(tempFile.getParentFile() + File.separator + tempClientFile);
```

to create a file in Notes document from uploaded file.

I noticed in some other code from others the following was used:

```
File correctedFile = new File( serverFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName );
```

Can the lacking of absolutepath can be the cause of file switch?

Ofcourse we have never noticed the occurrence under Testing in our Test environment.

Answer (score 2):

`.getAbsolutePath()` returns the full path whereas `.toString()` which is implicit used in your case returns just the abstract path.

Here is a [description of the difference](https://www.baeldung.com/java-path).

I use `.getAbsolutePath()` in my Domino backend code and never experienced the issue you describe.

Comment: Hi Knut, thanks for your input. I backed to the getAbsolutePath() method and monitoring the system now. I see no differences in path reference on both methods. I know in some cased the files are named identically so I am wondering if the Domino server has not cleaned up the files directly and in a later case is not capable of overwriting the existing file (when exists).